# Way to specify a static slice of variable length

Tags: rust, type-mismatch

Let's say I have a function with following signature:

```
fn validate(samples: &[(&str, &[Token])])
```

Where `Token` is a custom enum.
I would like to be able to write something along those lines:

```
    let samples = vec![
        ("a string", &[Token::PLUS, Token::MINUS, Token::PLUS]),
        ("another string", &[Token::MUL]),
    ];
    validate(&samples);
```

But code like this yields mismatched types compile error:

```
error: mismatched types:
expected `&[(&str, &[Token])]`,
   found `&collections::vec::Vec<(&str, &[Token; 3])>`
```

Is it possible to somehow convert the version with static length (`&[Token; 3]`) to a static slice (`&[Token]`)?
In other words, I would like to be able to specify a static slice in similar way I specify `&str`, as some kind of "slice literal".

Or I am doing it completely wrong?

EDIT:
In short, I would like to find a syntax that creates an array with static lifetime (or at least a lifetime that is as long as the `samples` vector's one), and returns slice of it.

Something similar to how strings work, where just typing "a string" gives me reference of type `&'static str`.

EDIT2:
@Pablo's answer provides pretty good solution to my particular problem, although it is not exactly what I have meant at first.

I guess that the exact thing I have in mind might not be possible, so I will just accept that one for now, unless something more in lines of my initial idea come around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In short, I would like to find a syntax that creates an array with
>   static lifetime (or at least a lifetime that is as long as the samples
>   vector's one), and returns slice of it.

You’d want something like this:

```
fn sliced(array: [Token; 3]) -> &'static [Token] { unimplemented!() }
```

So you could use it like this in your example:

```
let samples: Vec<(&str, &[Token])> = vec![
    ("a string", sliced([Token::PLUS, Token::MINUS, Token::PLUS])),
    // ...
```

But there are two problems with it. The first and most glaring is that you can’t get a `static` reference out of a function which doesn’t take in a `static` reference (in which case it would just return it).

Therefore, since you want a slice at least as long-lived as your array, either you declare a `const`/`static` slice (which requires also a `const`/`static` declaration of its array), or you declare the array with a `let` statement first, and then make the slice. (This is what is done at my first alternative, below.) If you create the array inside a use of `vec!`, together with its slice, the array end its life with `vec!`, rendering the slice invalid. As an illustration, consider this, which fails due to the same reason:

```
fn main() {
    let slice;
    {
        let array: [u8; 3] = [1,2,3];
        slice = &array;
    }
}
```

The second problem with the `sliced` function is that its input array has a fixed size, and you’d want to work generically over arrays of arbitrary size. However, this is currently not supported by Rust<sup>[1]</sup>. You have to work with slices in order to deal with arrays of arbitrary size.

One possibility, then, is to do the following [[playpen](http://is.gd/laHg7y)]:

```
enum Token {
    PLUS,
    MINUS,
    MUL,
}

fn validate(samples: &[(&str, &[Token])]) {
    unimplemented!()
}    

fn main() {
    let tokens_0 = [Token::PLUS, Token::MINUS, Token::PLUS];
    let tokens_1 = [Token::MUL];
    let samples: Vec<(&str, &[Token])> = vec![
        ("a string", &tokens_0),
        ("another string", &tokens_1),
    ];
    validate(&samples);
}
```

There are two changes here with respect to your code.

One, this code relies on implicit coercing of an array (`[T; N]`) as a slice (`&[T]`) by taking a reference to it. This is demanded by the declaration of `samples` as being of type `Vec<(&str, &[Token])>`. This is later satisfied, when using `vec!`, by passing references to the arrays, and thus eliciting the appropriate coercions.

Two, it creates the arrays of `Token` before using the `vec!` macro, which guarantees that they’ll live enough to be referenced from within the `Vec` it creates, keeping these references valid after `vec!` is done. This is necessary after resolving the previous type mismatch.

---

*Addendum*:

Or, for convenience, you may prefer to use a `Vec` instead of slices. Consider the following alternative [[playpen](http://is.gd/KuQhzu)]:

```
enum Token {
    PLUS,
    MINUS,
    MUL,
}

fn validate<T>(samples: &[(&str, T)]) where
    T: AsRef<[Token]>
{
    let _: &[Token] = samples[0].1.as_ref();

    unimplemented!()
}    

fn main() {
    let samples: Vec<(&str, Vec<Token>)> = vec![
        ("a string", vec![Token::PLUS, Token::MINUS, Token::PLUS]),
        ("another string", vec![Token::MUL]),
    ];
    validate(&samples);
}
```

In this case, the `AsRef<[Token]>` bound on the second element of the tuple accepts any type from which you may take a `&[Token]`, offering an `as_ref()` method which returns the expected reference. `Vec<Token>` is an example of such kind of type.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> “Rust does not currently support generics over the size of an array type.” [[source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html)]

Comment: Yeah, I considered this solution, but I intend to use this function with vector of samples that is much bigger than two, and it wouldn't be very convenient to do it this way.

Comment: Does your addendum cause the Vec<Token>s to be all moved into `validate` function? Or, because you take them as_ref, they stay in the original samples vector?

Comment: They stay. `samples` is being passed by reference, so there can be no move of the inner `Vec`.

Comment: Thanks for such detailed answer!
I hoped that maybe there exists a syntax that would allow to declare static arrays in similar way as static strings are declared, but I can go with your addendum.

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** this answer is not valid in this particular situation because the arrays pointed by the nested slices cannot outlive the vector because they are only allocated for the duration of their respective expressions, therefore slices to them can't be stored in the vector.

The proper way would be to either hoist slices to the upper level and put them before the vector, or to use an entirely different structure, e.g. nested `Vec`s. Examples of all of these are provided in [Pablo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35432880/788207).

---

You need to do this:

```
let samples = vec![
    ("a string", &[Token::PLUS, Token::MINUS, Token::PLUS] as &[_]),
    ("another string", &[Token::MUL] as &[_]),
];
validate(&samples);
```

Rust automatically converts references to arrays (`&[T; n]`) to slices (`&[T]`) when the target type is known, but in this case type inference doesn't work well because of the necessary deref coercion, so the compiler can't deduce that you need a slice instead of array and can't insert the appropriate conversion, thus you need to specify the type explicitly.

Also, there is no such thing as "static slice". The closest entity would be a slice with static lifetime, `&'static [T]`, but as far as I remember, this is not the case of it.

Comment: Yeah, I meant slice with static lifetime. Sorry for the confusion, I don't know all the terminology yet ;)

Comment: I think I'm probably wrong about static slices, I recall that this term is indeed frequently used as a synonym for "slice with static lifetime", so there *is* such thing. But again, in this case these slices won't have static lifetimes because they point to temporary variables which contain these arrays.

Comment: I tried this one, but it doesn't work unfortunately, due to the fact that the vector doesn't live long enough:
`token.rs:15:23: 15:63 error: borrowed value does not live long enough
 token.rs:15         ("a string", &[Token::PLUS, Token::MINUS, Token::PLUS] as &[_])`
(the same thing happens without `as &[_]`).
I guess that the big problem here is how to declare an array so that it has a static lifetime, but I get just ref to it. Something similar to how string literals work.
I could use @Pablo 's solution, but it has a bit too much boilerplate code.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I was under impression that it should work, but it seems that the compiler creates temporary variables as local as possible, and in a complex nested expression it would mean that the temporary variable is only valid for the duration of the inner expression. Therefore, I see no other way than the one suggested by @Pablo.

Answer (score 0):

I think a macro solves this beautifully:

```rust
macro_rules! s {
    [$($x:expr),*$(,)?] => { &[$($x),*] as &[_] }
}

// enum Token

// fn validate(_samples: &[(&str, &[Token])])

fn main() {
    let samples = s![
        ("a string", s![Token::PLUS, Token::MINUS, Token::PLUS]),
        ("another string", s![Token::MUL]),
    ];
    validate(&samples);
}
```

Link to [rust-playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=851c8accad9a2b707592f4af04678f52).